# stuck on validation error of email already taken

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I am following railscast #275 with testing the forgot me password. I am having troubles getting past the email has already been taken error. With the coding I have by following the tutorial I am suppose to receive this error, "error for no link with title or text "password". Instead this is what I am getting, "Validation failed: Email has already been taken (ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid)"

I have done a search, unable to find a solution for it.

Here's password_resets_spec.rb:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "PasswordResets" do
  it "emails user when requesting password reset"
    user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    visit login_path
    click_link "password"
    fill_in "Email", :with => user.email
    click_button "Reset Password"
  end
```

factories.rb:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence :email do |n| "test#{n}@example.com"
    end
    password "secret"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I did when I finally notice it started to work. I installed database cleaner. Then I did the commands:

rake db:reset 
rake db:migrate 
rake db:test:prepare

Following that I noticed I had to add a "do" to the end of " it "emails user when requesting password reset".

Now I have no errors and I can continue in my testing adventure. Thanks to those who tried to assist.

Answer (score 0):

The factory definition seems OK.

I would start by making sure that your test database is empty before running the spec. There may be an existing user record "test1@example.com" lingering. Also, have you tried to run only that example? Does it make any difference?

Comment: I ran rake db:test:prepare and it still does not change the error.

Comment: Are you running that example only? What happens when you add `User.count.should be_zero`as the first line of your spec?

Comment: Using test1 produces same error. Adding the user.count produces "undefined local variable or method `be_zero' "

Comment: That's odd; be_zero is a valid matcher. Can you try `User.count.should == 0`?

Comment: `fail_with': expected: 0 (RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)

Comment: That tells you that the problem is not in the factory, but in the fact that something is calling FactoryGirl.create before the code gets there. Check your before(:each) or before(:all) defined. Maybe show us your complete spec file.

Comment: The files I included in the original post are the only two spec files created besides the spec_helper. I literally ran into this error 2 minutes into starting the tests.

Comment: adding a before(:each) that deletes all users as AnkitG suggested will probably fix the problem, but won't help you find out the underlying cause; somewhere in your initialization you're calling FactoryGirl.create. I'd try a global search in your project for `FactoryGirl.create`. You might find a surprise

Comment: I did a search, and it appears only in the  password_resets_spec.rb file as listed in original post.

Comment: Either you create the user during initialization or it was already there, and you claim to have run db:test:prepare. Another try: do `RAILS_ENV=test rails c` and in the open irb session see what `User.count` returns.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like while running your test cases the factory that was created didn't rolled back/deleted the record.

add a `before(:each)` deletes previous records before the example executes

```
before(:each) do
User.delete_all
end
```

Comment: That just produces "undefined local variable or method `login_path' for #<Class:0x007fd15e2259e8> (NameError)"

Comment: Which I can fix by using " visit "/sessions/login" #login_path". So it still goes back to the original error of email already taken.

Comment: @pwz2000: I have updated the solution and deleting it with a `before(:each)` callback

Comment: undefined method `before' for main:Object (NoMethodError) is what I got. I have to be doing something wrong.

Comment: how are u placing the before_each callback ? This is the way it is defined https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-2/docs/hooks/before-and-after-hooks#define-before(:each)-block